# Asking about program logic or asking to see if a new algorithm should be use instead

Tags: discussion, scope

Say I am having a problem in one of my applications, as I have come upon a logic problem. I have a task that needs to be done in the logic of the program, but I cannot figure out a way that can do so.

It is not a language-specific problem, as it is just an algorithm I am unable to figure out. I have a pseudo-code example of the problem and why the code I can think of won't work.

Should I ask something on Stack Overflow asking for either ideas to solve the problems with what I have/or for an entirely new algorithm to implement?

Comment: This is not a place to ask for *ideas*.  Neither for asking for "best" anything. If you have pseudo-code that doesn't work and somehow can't figure why, folks might agree to look at it.

Comment: @PM77-1: Of course it is! "*I have problem …, how to solve it?*" is always asking for ideas to solve the problem. This is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At the very least, it seems like you've got the pieces there.

- What you're trying to do: this task within the logic of the program.
- What you've tried: the pseudo-code
- What's wrong with your attempt: why you think the code won't work
- The specific question: how to fix whatever issues your reasoning brought up (whether a small modification to the pseudocode or something bigger)

As long as you have all that in the question (and the question isn't unclear, poorly written, or a clear dupe), then you're probably good to go.

The only thing I'd probably add as a note is that with the "what's wrong with your attempt" part, the more clearly you explain why it won't work, the better (though I suppose that's also true of the rest of the question too. But it's definitely important to make the issue as clear as possible).

Comment: The main reason why I'm stressing clarity is that I think the biggest issue I've seen other than the prevalence of too many "write this code for me" questions is questions where it's just not clear enough what the specific task and issue are. It's not even about on or off topic at that point; it's whether people can understand the question enough to actually give a decent answer (or to figure out whether they're encountering the same issue).

Comment: Although this might work did you consider programmers.se?

Comment: Adding to what @DennisMeng says, including the research you have performed prior to posting a question is often the difference between people helping happily and a flurry of downvotes. Here we help people that can show they've put in some amount of work themselves and not just come asking for a handout.

Comment: I don't see how explaining in great detail an attempt that doesn't work is overly useful. "I tried [concept] but that failed because [conceptual flaw]" should be sufficient. Also you should not think your code will not work, you should know where and why it does not work and have a general idea how you would fix it and just ask how to express the fix in the language.

Comment: @nwp I mean, the explanation doesn't have to be extremely long; usually just one scenario where the code does the Wrong Thing is enough (as long as it's clear what it *should* do and what it's currently doing). I agree with the second sentence, but also note that they may not necessary know *how* to fix it, even if they know what the problem is.